# Conditional or on string comparison not working in block

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with a block where I am doing a string comparison on a block like so. Imagine my inventory_hostname is "hello-test.com", in other words this entire block should be skipped.

```
  - name: Do cool stuff
    block:
      
      - name: Some tasks
        set_fact: feeder="feeder.stuff.com"

      
    when:  ("'hello-prod.com' in inventory_hostname")
```

If I run it like above, it will skip it. However, If I run it with an or, like below it does not skip it even though inventory_hostname does not match either comparison

```
  - name: Do cool stuff
    block:
      
      - name: Some tasks
        set_fact: feeder="feeder.stuff.com"

      
    when:  ("'hello-prod.com' in inventory_hostname") or ("'hello-cool-prod.com' in inventory_hostname")
```

I've never had to use an or before in a when statement, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `when:` clause is actually messing around with quotes and I'm even surprised it does not fire an error. The correct syntax would be:

```yaml
    when: "'hello-prod.com' in inventory_hostname or 'hello-cool-prod.com' in inventory_hostname"
```

Meanwhile, you can shorten this condition and get rid off the enclosing double quotes by using the following

```yaml
    when: inventory_hostname is regex('hello(-cool)?-prod.com')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. It didn't dawn on me that the double set of double quotes would be the issue. And nope, ansible didn't fire any errors with that syntax! Regex works flawlessly, didn't realize you could do that in a string comparison.